# WP7 App Events in Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm seeing some unexpected things happening in the emulator.

When debugging and starting the app for the first time, the `Application_Launching` fires just fine. When clicking the start button, the `Application_Deactivated` event fires fine. When click the back button, the `Application_Activated` event fires fine.

If I click the start button then go to my apps and launch my app, no events are fired. I would assume either the `Application_Launching` or `Application_Activated` would fire when the app is launched every time, just a different event depending on how the app got there.

Is this an issue with the emulator or do I have the wrong assumptions here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the events get fired right. What you missed is that debugger get dettached when you are launching "new instance" of your app. ;)

Comment: Why does it work when the back button is pressed then, but not when the app is relaunched?

Comment: I see it now. It stays attached when you hit the windows button and you're able to hit the back button and it still works. As soon as you open your app by relaunching a new instance, as you said, the debugger detaches at that time. Thanks!